# Serial comunication with Arduino using 8086 assembly language

Tags: assembly, arduino, serial-port

I'm trying to connect arduino to a programin 8086 assembly language. I run the assembly program using DOSBox. The code that i'm using in assembly is:

```
mov ah, 00
mov al, 11000111b 
mov dx, 3
int 14h
MOV DX, 02E8H ;my port com4
MOV AH, 00
MOV AL, 'A' ;sending an 'A'
OUT DX,AL
```

And my arduino code is very simple,

```
if (Serial.available()) {
     int inByte = Serial.read();
     if(inByte == 65){
          digitalWrite(2,HIGH);
     }
}
```

I'm receiving something in Arduino, but I don't receive what I think I'm sending, the 'A' in this case.

If I send an 'A', or 'a', or 1, i get a 6 in arduino.

If I send an 'B', or 'b', or 2, i get a 24 in arduino.

If I send an 'C', or 'c', or 3, i get a 30 in arduino.

The same things with all letters, getting 0,6,24,30,96,102,120,126,128,134,152...

I also receive sometimes the number i said above and an 254.

I would be grateful with any help!

Comment: Could you provide us with a serial configuration you use on Arduino? Did you enable [serial communication](https://www.dosbox.com/wiki/Configuration:SerialPort) in DOSBOX? Did you try using `14h` for [sending](http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_14-1.html) instead of `out` instruction?

Comment: I already checked the dosbox configuration, and I tried with 14h but I couldn't send anything:

    MOV DX,00
    MOV AH,1
    MOV AL,'H'
    MOV DX,00
    INT 14H
    MOV AX,4C00H
    INT 21H

Comment: And what with serial configuration on Arduino? Edit your question and attach the initialization code.

Comment: Remember that when sending by `14h`, DX has to contain COM port number. 0 for COM1, 1 for COM2 etc. So in your case it should be 3 for COM4.

Comment: There probably is an UART configuration mismatch. With Arduino you can use `Serial.Begin` to set the UART settings. Under DosBox I don't think the settings have any effect since DosBox is simply rewriting into the OS port given in the config but *I may be wrong*. So you probably need to configure the serial at the OS level. The assembly initialization code seems to set 4800 bps,  no parity, 2 stops bit and 8-bit data. That's not the Arduino default.

Comment: The only thing that I didn’t shot from my arruino code is the “Serial.begin(9600);”. I tried with 14h, setting the port as mov dx, 3 (for com 4), But As I said above the program didn’t send anything. I made the  11000111b configuration using the port configuration showed from my device manager >> ports >> com4 >> properties, with 9600 bps :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this conf 11100011b it works for me

Comment: Thaaaank youuuuu♥